# Wordpress url and folder structure

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on migrating a static site to a new one based on Wordpress as a work platform.
The old site contains static html pages and a separate folder for the blog.
As a result I get the following URLs www.mysite.com / blog / category-name / post-number-one.
On the new site, WordPress turns the URL into www.mysite.com / category-name / post-number-one, removing the blog/ part.

For the sake of SEO, I must keep these urls like the old site. Is there a way using Wordpress to maintain this structure for blog posts only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the Wordpress admin, go to the Settings Tab, then the Permalinks menu. There will be a section called "Category base". Add "blog" there.

That should make it so the blog the categories are prefixed with /blog/category-name/post-number-one.

I had a similar issue. Basically I was running two Wordpress installations. One for pages and one for blog. Long story behind that.

But I eventually I needed to merge the WP installations.

In my case I also needed to go to Settings -> Reading and set the Posts page to "Blog", which was an empty page I named Blog also. This made it so the blog would be viewed at `http://mydomain/blog/`. I'm not sure if you wanted that too.

But yeah for the categories, you just need to add "Category base" under the permalinks setting.

Answer (score 1):

in your general settings, you can set a subfolder as your url, which can be hard to debug when you have problems, in my experience.

the other is that if you go into your clean urls settings page, you probably can simply add a string before your other `%params%`